How to avoid using local memory implicitly in CUDA?
I am working on a CUDA software path tracing renderer, and now I am stuck in the problem of suboptimal L1TEX local load/store access pattern. NCU told me that the bottleneck is within the following code (metric is L2 Theoretical Sectors Local). The following code is basically a stackless linear BVH traversal, and I marked the local memory access with \**\ comments.
__device__ float ray_intersect_bvh(
    const Ray& ray,
    const cudaTextureObject_t bvh_leaves,
    const cudaTextureObject_t node_fronts,
    const cudaTextureObject_t node_backs,
    ConstF4Ptr cached_nodes,
    const PrecomputedArray& verts,
    int& min_index,
    int& min_obj_idx,
    float& prim_u,
    float& prim_v,
    const int node_num,
    const int cache_num,
    float min_dist
) {
    bool valid_cache = false;         // whether we find valid node-intersection in cached nodes
    int node_idx     = 0;             // BVH tree node index
    float aabb_tmin  = 0;             // minimum intersection time of AABB (positive)
    // The following while lobe checks cached (in shared memory) node intersection
    // near root layers of the BVH tree are cached for faster access
    while (node_idx < cache_num && !valid_cache) {
        const LinearNode node(
            cached_nodes[node_idx],
            cached_nodes[node_idx + cache_num]
        );
        bool intersect_node = node.aabb.intersect(ray, aabb_tmin) && aabb_tmin < min_dist;
        int all_offset = node.aabb.base(), gmem_index = node.aabb.prim_cnt();
        int increment = (!intersect_node) * all_offset + (intersect_node && all_offset != 1) * 1;

        node_idx += increment;

        if (intersect_node && all_offset == 1) {
            valid_cache = true;
            node_idx = gmem_index;
        }
    }
    // if we find a valid intersection in cached nodes, we continue traversal in texture memory
    if (valid_cache) {
        while (node_idx < node_num) {
            const LinearNode node(tex1Dfetch<float4>(node_fronts, node_idx),
                            tex1Dfetch<float4>(node_backs, node_idx));
            bool intersect_node = node.aabb.intersect(ray, aabb_tmin) && aabb_tmin < min_dist;
            int beg_idx = 0, end_idx = 0;
            node.get_range(beg_idx, end_idx);
            
            int increment = (!intersect_node) * (end_idx < 0 ? -end_idx : 1) + int(intersect_node);
            if (intersect_node && end_idx > 0) {
                end_idx += beg_idx;
                // For BVH leaf node: traverse all the triangles within the range
                for (int idx = beg_idx; idx < end_idx; idx ++) {   /* Up to 44%.12 L2 theoretical sectors are accessed for this line */
                    /* SASS for the above line: LDL.LU, load 32 bit. */
                    bool valid  = false;
                    int2 obj_prim_idx = tex1Dfetch<int2>(bvh_leaves, idx);
                    float it_u = 0, it_v = 0, dist = Primitive::intersect(ray, verts, obj_prim_idx.y, it_u, it_v, obj_prim_idx.x >= 0);
                    valid = dist > EPSILON && dist < min_dist;
                    min_dist = valid ? dist : min_dist;
                    prim_u   = valid ? it_u : prim_u;
                    prim_v   = valid ? it_v : prim_v;
                    min_index = valid ? obj_prim_idx.y : min_index;
                    min_obj_idx = valid ? obj_prim_idx.x : min_obj_idx;
                }
            }
            node_idx += increment;
        }
    }
    return min_dist;
}


Also, the AABB intersection test has local memory issues, too. This is more severe, as NCU reported a bigger issue in local memory store pattern:
__device__ bool intersect(const Ray& ray, float& t_near) const {
    // Vec3 is a simple encapsulation of float3
    Vec3 invDir = ray.d.rcp();
    Vec3 t1s = (mini - ray.o) * invDir;             // long scoreboard
    Vec3 t2s = (maxi - ray.o) * invDir;

    float tmin = t1s.minimize(t2s).max_elem();
    float tmax = t1s.maximize(t2s).min_elem();
    t_near = tmin;
    return (tmax > tmin) && (tmax > 0);             /* SASS: STL, store 32 bit. local memory access problem */
}

Some other contexts:

-maxrregcount=56 is employed. My device is RTX3060 Laptop, and there should be no unexpected register spilling, since NCU told me that the max live registers in both the functions above is 52, so it should be sufficient.
No dynamic local array indexing, either (only shared, global, texture access).
NCU told me that: On average, only 1.1 (store) | 15.8 (load) of the 32 bytes transmitted  per sector are utilized by each thread. I am not sure why this is so low.

I wonder why compiler does this implicit local memory access, where I think there should be sufficient registers to use. I also want to know how to avoid this. I know that there is a keyword register in CPP, though it is mostly useless, it kind of implies that there is way to hint the the compiler.
The profiling report (with source attached within the report) can be found here, using NCU (I am using version 2024.3.1) can open it. In source, check out the L2 Theoretical Sectors Local.
The code itself can be found here.

It is going to be extremely difficult for anyone to comment on this in a way which you will find helpful. You have given us uncompileable code, and only device functions to look at. Register assignment and local memory spill is performed by the device code assembler/linker during the pass where device functions are integrated as calls or fully inlined. Guessing what might be going on and what countermeasures you might try is basically impossible based on what you have shared in your question

Have you tried compiling without -maxrregcount? This was a work-around of last resort in early CUDA on register-starved GPU architectures. It should now be used only in exceptional circumstances. What does the compiler report when you add the switch -Xptxas -v? Generally speaking, being able to diagnose register pressure issues without a minimal reproducer that others can build is not really possible.

@talonmies I am sorry for that. Here is the link to the code base and I will edit the post with a link to the NCU profiling report later.

@njuffa I did. The local memory accesses in the posts are gone, but they re-appear else where, for example: Vec3 invDir = ray.d.rcp(); in the second code block of the post, though all it does is get the reciprocal of a float3. Having no maxrregcount influences the occupancy and a 22% performance drop (22% more time taken per kernel call) is reported.

@Enigmatisms: There are 4900 lines of code in that GitHub repo. This isn’t how [SO] works. Craft a standalone example which demonstrates your problem and edit it into your question. Put bluntly, we are not here to help you. We are here to answer your question in the hope it will be useful to future visitors. When you delete or modify that GitHub repo, all the relevant information is lost.

Looking at your Github repository, you enabled separate compilation, which forces the compiler to spill some registers to local memory.
I can reproduce this locally and I can confirm that, when disabling separate compilation, local memory accesses are gone. You can verify this on Godbolt:

Code with -dc flag contains local memory accesses: https://godbolt.org/z/qbE66jjbo
Code without -dc flag does not contain local memory accesses: https://godbolt.org/z/87dYedWos

More information on the performance impact of separate compilation can be found in this post on NVIDIA developers blog.

I run into this problem regularly. When that happens I create a struct in shared memory and pass that around as a reference.
Make sure to use arrays of size blockDim if you need a parameter to be different per thread.
struct SharedData_t {
    Ray& ray;    //const params as normal members
    cudaTextureObject_t bvh_leaves;
    cudaTextureObject_t node_fronts;
    cudaTextureObject_t node_backs;
    mutable ConstF4Ptr cached_nodes; //non-const as mutable
    PrecomputedArray& verts;
    mutable int& min_index;
    mutable int& min_obj_idx;
    mutable float& prim_u;
    mutable float& prim_v;
    int node_num;
    int cache_num;
    mutable float min_dist;

    void init(/*lots of params*/); //you cannot construct a shared struct
};

...
__device__ __noinline__ SharedData_t& CallMeAtInitTime() {
  __shared__ SharedData_t a;
  a.init(/*lots of params*/)
  return a;
}

//pass the struct as const ref to protect the non-mutable members
__device__ float ray_intersect_bvh(const SharedData_t& a) {
... do stuff
 
}

Alternatively you can up the -maxrregcount. At the very least to 64, because it makes no sense to set this parameters to non-powers of 2. Try and up it to 128/256 and see if the local spilling goes away.
BTW, you do know that the 3090 has raytracing hardware to do exactly what you are trying to do? https://raytracing-docs.nvidia.com/

The solution on the top of my head is using shared memory, too. Yet I do want to explore some better solutions. I know there is hardware raytracing, but I delibrately
choose not to use it since I want to know how far I can get via pure software implementation.
